# chmod: Everything on SD Card Stuck On 755, Owner is Root

Tags: permissions, sd-card, chmod, chown

I am trying to access my SD card as a general user after it somehow changed to just Root access. I have tried several solutions, and none of them worked. Here is an attempt to chown eveything to ubuntu (Using a live USB here):

```
$ sudo chown ubuntu -R  /media/ubuntu
chown: changing ownership of ‘/media/ubuntu/JUSTADOO444/(Every single file/folder)’: Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of ‘/media/ubuntu/JUSTADOO444’: Operation not permitted
```

And after an attempt to chmod everything to 777:

Command:

```
$ sudo chmod 777 /media/ubuntu/ -v -R
mode of ‘/media/ubuntu/JUSTADOO444/(Everything)’ changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0777 (rwxrwxrwx)
```

And after a quick `ls -l`:

```
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root     4096 Sep  8 18:54 Sample Folder (Name Changed)
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root  4402055 Sep 16 11:53 Sample Presentation.odp
```

This is getting on my nerves. I have to use sudo before every single thing I try to do to my SD card. (It has a LOT of data on it, too, and I am unlucky enough to not have a space to backup. If only my 16gb flash drive wasn't being used for Ubuntu booting only...)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I use 'chmod' on an NTFS (or FAT32) partition?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/11840/how-do-i-use-chmod-on-an-ntfs-or-fat32-partition)

Comment: (assuming your SD card is formatted `exFAT` or something)

Comment: Mine, in Disks, is: W95 FAT32 (LBA). I'll try the linked question anyways.

Comment: The linked question/answer failed me. Everything's still as root.

Comment: Add the output of `mount | grep /media/ubuntu` to your question, please.

Answer (score 2):

How is your SD card `mount`ed?

```
mount | grep /media/ubuntu
```

Do you see `ro` or `rw`? You can remount it read/write by:

```
sudo mount -o remount,rw /media/ubuntu
```

If you read `man 8 mount` you can add an entry into `/etc/fstab` (`man 5 fstab`) that will allow a specified user, or all users to `mount` (and own) the SD card.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding uid=your_username to the mount options. It worked for me and changes the Owner to me everytime I plug it in

Answer (score 0):

For me this was because I had an SD card formatted as a FAT32 filesystem.
[Fat32 doesn't support file permissions](https://askubuntu.com/a/118200/317983).