# Is it possible to mount a drive without changing the directory owner to root?

Tags: mount, hard-drive

When I'm mounting a drive it changes both the owner of the directory and the write and read premissions. For some reason chmod command doesn't work, and I can't change it with the UI because of the ownership. Is there a way to mount the drive but keep the ownership?
I've used sudo mount to mount it and tried sudo chown and sudo chmod to change ownership and premissions respectively, none of them worked. the partition type is FAT32

Comment: Given the initial information in your question, the answer is “it depends”. Can you [edit] your question to include: (0) the type of file system you are mounting (Ext4 / NTFS / etc) (1) the command you are using to mount the partition(s). With this, it becomes possible to offer an answer 

Comment: How are you mounting the drive? What does `mount` say about the drive? Are you running Ubuntiu? Read `man mount`. You can specify ownership as you `mount`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I change file permissions on a FAT32 drive?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/118199/how-do-i-change-file-permissions-on-a-fat32-drive)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I'm mounting a drive it changes both the owner of the directory and the write and read premissions.

... to the user you mount it with otherwise it mounts to root.

> For some reason chmod command doesn't work, and I can't change it with the UI because of the ownership.

chmod only works on posix compliant systems. That is for instance ext, and not ntfs or fat.

> Is there a way to mount the drive but keep the ownership? I've used sudo mount to mount it and tried sudo chown and sudo chmod to change ownership and premissions respectively, none of them worked. the partition type is FAT32

FAT32: during the mount you tell it to use a specific user. Example:

```
sudo mount -t vfat /dev/{device} /media/{mountpoint} -o rw,uid=1000,gid=1000,umask=113,dmask=002
```

where 1000 is your admin and files are set to `rw-rw-r--` and folders are set to `rwxrwxr-x` (it uses umask so a reversed chmod).

```
id -u {username}
```

to find the userid of a user.

You can use the actual username in /etc/fstab if you want.

Comment: it worked, now I'm the owner, but chmod still does not work...

Comment: and it never ever will. chmod is for posix compliant filesystems. fat is not 1 of those.

Comment: so I can't allow all users to write this drive?

Comment: yes you can. see the gid (group id) option

Comment: I didn't understand... do you want me to change the drive's gid?