# How do I change permissions on a FAT32 drive?

Tags: usb, flash, usb-drive, fat32

My USB type is FAT32. I tried to solve problem using terminal (https://askubuntu.com/a/96929/130182), but it gives me an error:

```
mount: special device /dev/sdb1 does not exist
```

How I can change permissions on FAT32 flash-drive?

Comment: You can't change permissions for files on `FAT` filesystems. Your error suggests that you have specified the wrong device name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your are on the wrong track.

The message has nothing to do with a permission problem.

The problem is that the *usb drive* is not recognized below `/dev/sdb1`.

This may have two different reasons:

1. The stick has no partition table. That means that the file system is on `/dev/sdb` (not the 1st partition). Try to mount instead `/dev/sdb`.
2. The stick is assigned to another device name. Please have a look on the `dmesg` output just after inserting the stick.