# How to change permissions on a usb stick?

Tags: permissions

I have two usb sticks,both are recognized automatically but when I try to write or copy files to either it comes up with error saying I do not have permission to copy to this destination folder.I have changed the permissions in properties but it will not let me to change the permissions for the actual usb stick. What can I do?

EDIT: USB stick info from comments:

```
Solaris Disk /dev/sdb: 2065 MB, 2065694720 64 heads, 8 sectors/track, 7880 cylinders, total 4034560 sectors Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes Disk identifier: 0xc3072e18 Device Boot Start End Blocks Id System /dev/sdb1 * 32 4034559 2017264 6
```

Comment: Your usb sticks are in this [list](http://www.fencepost.net/2010/03/usb-flash-drives-with-hardware-write-protection/)?

Answer (score 10):

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

will tell you what's mounted. Then run:

```
sudo chmod 666 /dev/sdY
```

where sdY is the device assignment for your USB drive.That will allow you to read and write.

Comment: Hi I've tried this but below is what returned so I don't think i did it right.Can you help?     Disk /dev/sdc: 16.0 GB, 15977152512 bytes

Comment: what does sudo fdisk -l say

Comment: Hi As I do not know how to do screenshot , I will post as 3 comments.                                                    Disk /dev/sda: 320.1 GB, 320072933376 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 38913 cylinders, total 625142448 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000b6638

Comment: Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048   621774847   310886400   83  Linux
/dev/sda2       621776894   625141759     1682433    5  Extended
/dev/sda5       621776896   625141759     1682432   82  Linux swap / Solaris Disk /dev/sdb: 2065 MB, 2065694720 bytes

Comment: 64 heads, 8 sectors/track, 7880 cylinders, total 4034560 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes Disk identifier: 0xc3072e18
Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1   *          32     4034559     2017264    6  FAT16

Comment: Do you know what I can do?

Comment: Not really, nothing you posted is about a usb stick.

Comment: Hi, I am sorry but I thought it was, since I believed that what I posted was the results was the result of fdisk -l. If these are not the correct results, does this mean anything to you.            /dev/sdb1 on /media/usb0 type vfat (rw,noexec,nodev,sync,noatime,nodiratime)
deprima@deprima-K53U:/media/usb0/Google$

Comment: this doesnt work its not this simple

Answer (score 3):

Depends on how you have formated the USB drive.. often they are fat32, and if so, not that many things to setup.

if you format at extX then you and simply use `chmod` and `chown` to set permission and owner

edit: I see that from a comment above it looks like it has fat16 format. so it does not support file permissions.

see [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/96929/6161) for a way to mount it using different permissions