# How Can I Install A Steam game On A Flash Drive

Tags: games, usb-drive, steam

I'm Wondering if I Install Garry's Mod On A flash Drive?

Comment: Related: [What happens if you install a Steam game to a removable drive?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/126505)

Answer (score 2):

- You plug in your flash drive.
- Open Steam and from the menu
- Choose Settings.
- Go to the Downloads tab on top.
- Click on the button "steam library folders".
- Then Add library folder.
- Choose the folder that your flash drive is mounted in. Should be in `/media`.
- Create a new folder and select it. Your folder should be added to the list.
- Close settings. When you download a game you will be asked which library you want to install it to.

Comment: This [answer with screenshots](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/75999/download-games-from-steam-to-another-drive/98172#98172) might be interesting.

Comment: I Did What You Said But It Says This, 'New Steam library folder must be on a filesystem mounted with execute permissions' What Do I Do?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/96923/how-do-i-change-permissions-on-a-fat32-formatted-drive