# Not being able to change permission of home folder from root to <username>

Tags: home-directory

I have three partitions on my laptop one for storage one for windows and the other one for ubuntu. I changed my home folder using this guide: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving

but now I am not being able to change permission of home folder (which is set to root) to . It is causing some issues in my system for example pulse audio is not working anymore hence no sound.
please help me out Thanks.

Comment: What filesystem does the partition where your home is use?

Comment: it uses fat32 filesystem

Comment: Please remove the edited-in screenshot (it's not helpful) and post the output of "mount".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The FAT32 filesystem doesn't support attributes like ownership and have the owner set with the mount options.

You need to format the partition with an advanced filesystem like ext, btrfs or ntfs, although I'd avoid the latter.

See https://askubuntu.com/a/96929/6161 on how to remount using different permissions.

Comment: sorry brother its ntfs