# Change directory owner/group from root to a user

Tags: permissions, directory, root, users, ownership

when trying to change the ownership of a directory i get the error:

```
chown: changing ownership of '/home/tadpoles': Operation not permitted
```

I even get the above message when i do sudo -s and run it as root.

Here is the command i try to run:

```
sudo chown toadmanager /home/tadpoles
```

Also, here is the perms of the directory when i run ls -l: (SharedFolder is in the directory and it also cannot be modified)

```
total 32
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 32768 Feb 16 12:23 SharedFolder
```

I am fairly new to ubuntu and linux in general so any help is appreciated, i also already looked up some other guides and chgrp did not work either. I should also mention that this directory is on a different drive which is mounted to /home/tadpoles and the file system is vfat

Comment: You should not be running Linux partitions on a vfat format. That applies to EFI partitions for booting. Chown and chmod permission commands work on ext4 format, which is what you should be running Linux on.

Comment: See also [Why chown command can't take effect?](https://askubuntu.com/a/747136/178692)

Comment: @Paul Beson, Incorrectly states not to use fat for an `EFI` partition to boot from, that is part of the standard it requires that there be fat partition for an `EFI` boot partition for the machines to boot `EFI`. A comment on `FAT` and permission changes is, it does not support permissions.

Answer (score 0):

If you could run this command and post the output to the original question, it might help.

```
    cat /etc/passwd | grep toadmanager
```

If you get no output from the command it means that toadmanager is not a user on your system.

You can search for **Users**  in the **Activities** panel in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, unlock the application, and use the green pushbutton to "Add User"  for toadmanager.

Comment: Hey thanks for your reply, toadmanager is a sudo user that i can log into. I also have no physical access to the machine, this is all over ssh

Answer (score 0):

Solved, i had a vfat file system so i went in a reformatted the drive in ext4. Everything works properly now!

Thanks [Paul Benson](https://askubuntu.com/users/802479/paul-benson)