# Recover GRUB-EFI after installing Ubuntu on a Mac

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi, mac

I installed Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS on an iMac (I deleted the MacOS, as I have no interested in dual boot in this case), but now I can't recover the GRUB. I've tried every approach after searching for ways to do it, but none of them worked.

When I run efibootmgr, I get this:

```
BootCurrent: 0000
Timeout: 5 seconds
BootOrder: 0000,0081
Boot0000* ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,69216dcf-c0a1-4fd7-a535-07c0c3dfaae8,0x800,0x100000)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi)
Boot0080*   PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1f,0x2)/Sata(0,0,0)/HD(1,GPT,69216dcf-c0a1-4fd7-a535-07c0c3dfaae8,0x800,0x100000)/File(\EFI\BOOT\BOOTX64.efi)
Boot0081* Mac OS X  PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1f,0x2)/Sata(0,0,0)/HD(2,GPT,00001b41-18fd-0000-ab5c-0000ac210000,0x64028,0x3a1ec0c0)
BootFFFF*   PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1d,0x7)/USB(0,0)/USB(3,0)/HD(2,0,00000000000000000000000000000000,0x2eec,0x1340)/File(\EFI\BOOT\BOOTX64.efi)
```

Does anyone have any ideas about what I should try next?

TIA.

Comment: Those with a Mac seem to use rEFInd a lot. I have used it on my PC for emergency boot. http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/ &
https://askubuntu.com/questions/908677/want-to-view-contents-of-boot-efi-in-xubuntu-dont-have-permissions

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Boot Repair**. It will regenerate your GRUB installation. To install it:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt install --assume-yes boot-repair
boot-repair
```

If you cannot access to Ubuntu anymore, use a live CD/USB: https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/try-ubuntu-before-you-install#1-getting-started
and select the "Try Ubuntu" option. Then install there Boot Repair and follow instructions.