# What external SSD hard drives can be used for a Ubuntu install?

Tags: boot, usb, hard-drive, ssd

I have previously installed Ubuntu on both a USB stick and an SSD drive connected through USB. Nevertheless, I have failed to do so recently with the SanDisk Ultra Portable SSD external hard disk. The reason seems to be that a boot partition can't be created on this disk (if anyone knows otherwise please leave me a comment). Neither will such installation work on any USB stick; it works on some but doesn't work on others. I very much need such a portable installation on a (rugged, portable) external SSD of at least 250GB, ideally 500GB. Does anyone have any experience with what works among those currently available (Western Digital, Seagate...) ?

Same question for currently-available USB sticks. I'm genuinely more interested in knowing what are the USB drives that would work than in workarounds trying to fix the install on the SanDisk, although the latter is also an option.

Comment: Does this link help.  https://superuser.com/questions/1519497/grub-install-failing-on-ssd

Comment: My experience is different, the installer never seems to complain it fails. It behaves as if everything is fine, but then the disk just won't boot. On the other hand, probably rEFInd would help, but I'm not sure where/how to install/use it.

Comment: http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/ &
https://askubuntu.com/questions/908677/want-to-view-contents-of-boot-efi-in-xubuntu-dont-have-permissions
Did you put an ESP on external drive? And reinstall grub to external drive?  Ubuntu's Ubiquity only installs grub2 boot loader to first drive. Posted work around to manually unmount & mount correct ESP during install #23 & #26
 https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1396379

Comment: As I said, I installed Ubuntu on external drives before. In doing so, I either disconnected the internal drive or flagged its boot partition as `msfsdata`, created ESP partition on the external drive, installed on it, then returned the internal drive flag to `esp, boot`. I'm not an expert, but this procedure did work before.