# using gpart & testdisk to recover GPT for Files from damaged HFS+ (Apple) HD

Tags: partitioning, usb, data-recovery, hfs+

I want to recover **gpt** from my external USB Hard Disk.

*I tried these questions*:

https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/296151/recover-files-from-corrupted-external-usb-hd-macos-sierra

https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/297562/using-gpt-unable-to-open-device-resource-busy

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/388982/recover-files-from-hsf-usb-external-hd-test-on-centos-7-to-diagnostic

**ON UBUNTU**:

http://blog.abhiomkar.in/2009/04/12/repair-fix-mac-hfs-partition-using-ubuntu-cd/

*All these procedure take a long time*

Sorry if my question is not conclusive about this command result, because (I'm registering a live USB), I will be editing!

Using **fdisk**:

```
$ sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdd
fdisk: cannot open /dev/sdd: Input/output error
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$
```

Using **gpart**:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo gpart /dev/sdd

*** Fatal error: cannot get sector size on dev(/dev/sdd).
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$
```

Using **parted**

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo parted /dev/sdd
Warning: Error fsyncing/closing /dev/sdd1: Input/output error
Retry/Ignore? i
```

Using **testdisk**

Following this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H_EwWNw2lso&t=996s

```
TestDisk 7.0, Data Recovery Utility, April 2015
Christophe GRENIER <grenier@cgsecurity.org>
http://www.cgsecurity.org

  TestDisk is free software, and
comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.

Select a media (use Arrow keys, then press Enter):
 Disk /dev/sda - 121 GB / 113 GiB - APPLE SSD SM0128G
 Disk /dev/sdb - 8017 MB / 7646 MiB - Kingston DT 101 II
>Disk /dev/sdd - 1000 GB / 931 GiB - ADATA HD710







>[Proceed ]  [  Quit  ]

Note: Disk capacity must be correctly detected for a successful recovery.
If a disk listed above has incorrect size, check HD jumper settings, BIOS
detection, and install the latest OS patches and disk drivers.
```

Now this procedure take about 1 hour.

```
TestDisk 7.0, Data Recovery Utility, April 2015
Christophe GRENIER <grenier@cgsecurity.org>
http://www.cgsecurity.org


Disk /dev/sdd - 1000 GB / 931 GiB - ADATA HD710

Please select the partition table type, press Enter when done.
 [Intel  ] Intel/PC partition
>[EFI GPT] EFI GPT partition map (Mac i386, some x86_64...)
 [Humax  ] Humax partition table
 [Mac    ] Apple partition map
 [None   ] Non partitioned media
 [Sun    ] Sun Solaris partition
 [XBox   ] XBox partition
 [Return ] Return to disk selection




Note: Do NOT select 'None' for media with only a single partition. It's very
rare for a disk to be 'Non-partitioned'.
```

**Analyse**

```
TestDisk 7.0, Data Recovery Utility, April 2015
Christophe GRENIER <grenier@cgsecurity.org>
http://www.cgsecurity.org


Disk /dev/sdd - 1000 GB / 931 GiB - ADATA HD710
     CHS 953869 64 32 - sector size=512

>[ Analyse  ] Analyse current partition structure and search for lost partitions
 [ Advanced ] Filesystem Utils
 [ Geometry ] Change disk geometry
 [ Options  ] Modify options
 [ Quit     ] Return to disk selection







Note: Correct disk geometry is required for a successful recovery. 'Analyse'
process may give some warnings if it thinks the logical geometry is mismatched.
```

**NOTHING?**

```
TestDisk 7.0, Data Recovery Utility, April 2015
Christophe GRENIER <grenier@cgsecurity.org>
http://www.cgsecurity.org

Disk /dev/sdd - 1000 GB / 931 GiB - CHS 953869 64 32
Current partition structure:
     Partition                  Start        End    Size in sectors

Trying alternate GPT












                P=Primary  D=Deleted
>[Quick Search]
                            Try to locate partition
```

This procedure take a long time (6 hours aprox)

```
TestDisk 7.0, Data Recovery Utility, April 2015
Christophe GRENIER <grenier@cgsecurity.org>
http://www.cgsecurity.org

Disk /dev/sdd - 1000 GB / 931 GiB - CHS 953869 64 32

     Partition                  Start        End    Size in sectors


No partition found or selected for recovery











>[  Quit  ]
                              Return to main menu
```

**Some proposal to recover gpt and recover my files?**

**EDIT 2**

Previously I tryed with **ddrescue** in **macOS**

```
MacBook-Air:~ joseluisbz$ diskutil list
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *121.3 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:          Apple_CoreStorage Macintosh HD            120.5 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3

/dev/disk1 (internal, virtual):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD           +120.1 GB   disk1
                                 Logical Volume on disk0s2
                                 7887C476-CBE0-4D10-B95A-5C79F83B20D7
                                 Unencrypted

/dev/disk2 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *1.0 TB     disk2
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk2s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS HD710A                  999.9 GB   disk2s2

/dev/disk3 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *1.0 TB     disk3
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk3s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS ADATAHD                 999.9 GB   disk3s2

MacBook-Air:~ joseluisbz$
```

`/dev/disk2` (`DESTINY`) (/Volumes/HD710A/) `/dev/disk3` (`SOURCE`)

Now using `ddrescue`!

```
MacBook-Air:~ joseluisbz$ sudo /usr/local/Custom/ddrescue/bin/ddrescue --idirect --retry-passes=3 /dev/disk3 /Volumes/HD710A/ADATAHD.img /Volumes/HD710A/ADATAHD.log
ddrescue: Direct disc access not available.
MacBook-Air:~ joseluisbz$ sudo /usr/local/Custom/ddrescue/bin/ddrescue --retry-passes=3 /dev/disk3 /Volumes/HD710A/ADATAHD.img /Volumes/HD710A/ADATAHD.log
GNU ddrescue 1.22
     ipos:        0 B, non-trimmed:        0 B,  current rate:       0 B/s
     opos:        0 B, non-scraped:        0 B,  average rate:       0 B/s
non-tried:    9223 PB,  bad-sector:        0 B,    error rate:       0 B/s
  rescued:        0 B,   bad areas:        0,        run time:          0s
pct rescued:    0.00%, read errors:        0,  remaining time:         n/a
                              time since last successful read:         n/a
Copying non-tried blocks... Pass 1 (forwards)
```

I can't see the files on **macOS**, nothig was rescued!

**On Ubuntu Side**

I can see the files with `tree` command and using browser I can see the folders.
[image: Folders of ADATAHD]

My procedure, I know only need gddrescue hfsprogs

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo -i
root@ubuntu:~#
root@ubuntu:~# apt-get install gddrescue testdisk gparted gpart hfsprogs tree
root@ubuntu:~# umount /media/ubuntu/HD710A
root@ubuntu:~# mkdir /home/ubuntu/HD710A
root@ubuntu:~# mount -t hfsplus -o force,rw /dev/sdd2 /home/ubuntu/HD710A
root@ubuntu:~# rm -rf /home/ubuntu/HD710A/ADATAHD.img
rm: cannot remove '/home/ubuntu/HD710A/ADATAHD.img': Read-only file system
root@ubuntu:~#



root@ubuntu:~# df
Filesystem     1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
udev             4020396         0   4020396   0% /dev
tmpfs             807376      9880    797496   2% /run
/dev/sdb         1571328   1571328         0 100% /cdrom
/dev/loop0       1517312   1517312         0 100% /rofs
aufs             4036872    225208   3811664   6% /
tmpfs            4036872     56536   3980336   2% /dev/shm
tmpfs               5120         4      5116   1% /run/lock
tmpfs            4036872         0   4036872   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs            4036872       592   4036280   1% /tmp
tmpfs             807372       176    807196   1% /run/user/999
/dev/sdd2      960051928     77852 911136360   1% /home/ubuntu/HD710A
/dev/sde2      976426672 342555812 633870860  36% /media/ubuntu/ADATAHD
root@ubuntu:~#
```

That means:
`/dev/sde2` will be `source`
`/dev/sdd2` will be `destiny`

I formatted with `**gparted**`

```
root@ubuntu:~# umount /home/ubuntu/HD710A
root@ubuntu:~# mount -t ext4 -o rw /dev/sdd2 /home/ubuntu/HD710A
root@ubuntu:~# touch /home/ubuntu/HD710A/somefile.txt
```

Now using **ddrescue**

```
root@ubuntu:~# ddrescue  --idirect  --retry-passes=3  /dev/sde2  /home/ubuntu/HD710A/ADATAHD.img  /home/ubuntu/HD710A/ADATAHD.log
GNU ddrescue 1.21
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
     ipos:  230869 MB, non-trimmed:   14942 kB,  current rate:       0 B/s
     opos:  230869 MB, non-scraped:        0 B,  average rate:       0 B/s
non-tried:  999845 MB,     errsize:        0 B,      run time: 11h 28m 11s
  rescued:        0 B,      errors:        0,  remaining time:         n/a
percent rescued:   0.00%      time since last successful read: 11h 28m 11s
Copying non-tried blocks... Pass 1 (forwards)
```

HERE the **tree** command result on my to be recovered Hard Disk (some files are erased in the result saving characters on this question).

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ tree /media/ubuntu/ADATAHD/
/media/ubuntu/ADATAHD/
├── Applications
│   ├── AlphaCombo.app
│   │   └── Contents
│   │       └── Info.plist
│   ├── Apple.new
│   │   └── GarageBand.app
│   │       └── Contents
│   │           ├── _CodeSignature
│   │           │   └── CodeResources
│   │           └── _MASReceipt
│   ├── Apple.old
│   │   ├── GarageBand.app
│   │   │   └── Contents
│   │   │       └── Info.plist
│   │   ├── iMovie.app
│   │   │   └── Contents
│   │   ├── Keynote.app
│   │   │   └── Contents
│   │   ├── Numbers.app
│   │   │   └── Contents
│   │   └── Pages.app
│   │       └── Contents
│   ├── ColorMath.app
│   │   └── Contents
│   │       ├── _CodeSignature
│   │       ├── Info.plist
│   │       └── PkgInfo
│   ├── iBooks.app
│   ├── iBooks Author.app
│   │   └── Contents
│   │       ├── Info.plist
│   │       ├── PkgInfo
│   │       └── version.plist
│   ├── Kid's Alphabets.app
│   │   └── Contents
│   │       ├── _CodeSignature
│   │       │   └── CodeResources
│   │       ├── Info.plist
│   │       └── PkgInfo
│   ├── Lola's Math Train FREE.app
│   │   └── Contents
│   └── PreschoolNumbers.app
│       └── Contents
│           ├── _CodeSignature
│           │   └── CodeResources
│           ├── Info.plist
│           ├── _MASReceipt
│           └── PkgInfo
├── BootCamp_4.0.4326
│   ├── BootCamp64.xml
│   ├── Boot Camp Installation & Setup Guide.pdf
│   ├── Boot Camp Manual de instalación y configuración.pdf
│   ├── BootCamp.xml
│   └── Drivers
│       └── Apple
│           ├── AppleBluetoothBroadcomInstaller.exe
│           ├── AppleBluetoothEnablerInstaller.exe
│           ├── AppleBluetoothInstaller.exe
│           ├── AppleDisplayInstaller.exe
│           ├── AppleiSightInstaller.exe
│           ├── AppleKeyboardInstaller.exe
│           ├── AppleMultiTouchTrackPadInstaller.exe
│           ├── AppleNullDriver.exe
│           ├── AppleODDInstaller.exe
│           ├── AppleRemoteInstaller.exe
│           ├── AppleSoftwareUpdate.msi
│           ├── AppleTrackpadInstaller.exe
│           ├── AppleWirelessMouse.exe
│           ├── AppleWirelessTrackpad.exe
│           ├── BootCamp64.msi
│           ├── BootCamp.msi
│           └── x64
├── BootCamp_5.1.5621
│   ├── AutoUnattend.xml
│   └── BootCamp
│       ├── BootCamp.xml
│       └── Drivers
│           └── Apple
├── Desktop Items
│   ├── JDownloader2 -> /Users/josebernal/bin/JDownloader 2.0/JDownloader2.app
│   ├── VirtualBox - CentOS 7 Guest
│   └── VirtualBox - Win Guest
├── Developments
│   ├── jnativehook
│   ├── jnativehook-2.1.0.log
│   └── jnativehook-2.1.0.zip
├── Documentos
│   ├── 03_2017_0000650570.pdf
│   ├── AEZR
│   ├── bookmarks_6_15_17.html
│   ├── CEC-00122521907.pdf
│   ├── certificado_1011223690.pdf
│   ├── certificado_22521907.pdf
│   ├── certificado_72195997.pdf
│   ├── ContratoArrendamiento01.png
│   ├── ContratoArrendamiento02.png
│   ├── ContratoArrendamiento03.png
│   ├── ControatoArrendamiento
│   │   ├── ContratoArrendamiento2.png
│   │   ├── ContratoArrendamiento3.png
│   │   ├── ContratoArrendamiento.docx
│   │   ├── ContratoArrendamiento.pdf
│   │   └── ContratoArrendamiento.png
│   ├── Convencion
│   │   ├── Convencion IPUC BAQ 2017-00.mov
│   │   ├── Convencion IPUC BAQ 2017-01.mov
│   │   ├── Convencion IPUC BAQ 2017-02.mov
│   │   ├── Convencion IPUC BAQ 2017-03.mov
│   │   ├── Convencion IPUC BAQ 2017-04.mov
│   │   ├── Convencion IPUC BAQ 2017-05.mov
│   │   ├── Convencion IPUC BAQ 2017-06.mov
│   │   └── Convencion IPUC BAQ 2017-07.mov
│   ├── DOC-20170405-WA0023 (Alcira Zuluaga)_Tutela.pdf
│   ├── DriversForSound
│   │   ├── amd64_hdaudio.inf_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.14393.0_none_42d4a14a7e22ada2
│   │   │   ├── hdaudio.inf
│   │   │   └── HdAudio.sys
│   │   ├── amd64_ks.inf_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.14393.0_none_e312ad1d03762a04
│   │   ├── amd64_wdmaudio.inf_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.14393.0_none_8ddbc48e30d84d28
│   │   ├── drmkaud.sys
│   │   ├── drmk.sys
│   │   ├── hdaudio.inf
│   │   ├── hdaudio.inf_amd64_04c3e2018e8e6dfd
│   │   │   ├── hdaudio.inf
│   │   │   ├── hdaudio.PNF
│   │   │   └── HdAudio.sys
│   │   ├── hdaudio.PNF
│   │   ├── HdAudio.sys
│   │   ├── ks.inf
│   │   ├── ks.inf_amd64_8b65b50645c5b6bc
│   │   ├── ks.PNF
│   │   ├── ksthunk.sys
│   │   ├── MsApoFxProxy.dll
│   │   ├── portcls.sys
│   │   ├── SysFxUI.dll
│   │   ├── wdmaudio.inf
│   │   ├── wdmaudio.inf_amd64_bf7ec511830b3442
│   │   ├── wdmaudio.PNF
│   │   └── WMALFXGFXDSP.dll
│   ├── Exporting VM from VirtualBox To VMWare Fusion.mov
│   ├── Factura Celular J1(E2).png
│   ├── Factura Celular J1(E).png
│   ├── Factura Celular J1.png
│   ├── Factura MacBook Air Apple 20160801.png
│   ├── FalloTutela
│   │   ├── Recibos
│   │   │   ├── Recibo2.png
│   │   │   ├── Recibo3.png
│   │   │   └── Recibo.png
│   │   ├── TutelaAlcira01.png
│   │   └── TutelaAlcira02.png
│   ├── FindOriginal123
│   ├── Foto_AndinoGivenchy.png
│   ├── FotosFamilia_BernalZuluaga.jpeg
│   ├── Fotos_YosefDani_20170810_Director_20p.png
│   ├── Fotos_YosefDani_20170810_Director.png
│   ├── Fotos_YosefDani_20170810_Directorx4.png
│   ├── Fotos_YosefDani_20170810_Group_20p.png
│   ├── Fotos_YosefDani_20170810_Group_20p_Publish.png
│   ├── Fotos_YosefDani_20170810_Group.png
│   ├── Fotos_YosefDani(Director)_20170810.png
│   ├── Guinnea-Bisau.pdf
│   ├── HistoriaYosefDani.docx
│   ├── Impresionante niño de 11 años revela a Jesús.mp4
│   ├── Informe Misionero de Guinea Bissau
│   ├── Jesucristo Es Dios_Bf.mp3
│   ├── Jesucristo Es Dios_BfSpeed130P_Amp.mp3
│   ├── Jesucristo Es Dios_BfSpeed130P_Amp.wav
│   ├── Jesucristo Es Dios_BfSpeed130P, Amp.wav
│   ├── Jesucristo Es Dios_BfSpeed130P.wav
│   ├── La Balanza de Dios.mp4
│   ├── Matrícula - Dipl. JAVA SE PROGRAMMER - JAVA-2017-2-COL-BOG-_encrypted_.pdf
│   ├── Presentation iTelkom V3.b.pptx
│   ├── Recibo GAS
│   │   ├── Facturas Gas0.png
│   │   ├── Facturas Gas1.png
│   │   ├── Facturas Gas Another.png
│   │   └── Small
│   │       ├── Facturas Gas0.png
│   │       └── Facturas Gas1.png
│   ├── ~$storiaYosefDani.docx
│   └── YosefDani
│       ├── Learning Fonts
│       └── Ordenes SanJose Otorrino
├── Documents
│   ├── Celular GS7102 Alcira
│   │   └── Collage
│   │       ├── 2015-02-23 10.20.01.jpg
│   │       ├── 2015-02-23 10.23.51.jpg
│   │       ├── 2015-02-23 15.02.13.jpg
│   │       └── 2015-02-23 15.03.54.jpg
│   ├── diffListFiles.txt
│   ├── GeneticaYosef_201703XX
│   ├── Introducción a Drupal.mp4
│   ├── List_20170206-080000.txt
│   ├── List_20170206-080730.txt
│   ├── List_20170206-081310.txt
│   ├── List_20170206-084310.txt
│   ├── Outlook for Mac Archive(iTelkom).olm
│   ├── Outlook for Mac Archive(iTelkom).pst
│   └── Scans
│       ├── Cardiopediatría002.png
│       ├── Cardiopediatría003.png
│       ├── Cardiopediatría00.png
│       ├── Cardiopediatría_YosefDani_20170315_01b.png
│       ├── Cardiopediatría_YosefDani_20170315_01.png
│       ├── Cardiopediatría_YosefDani_20170315_02b.png
│       ├── Cardiopediatría_YosefDani_20170315_02.png
│       ├── Cardiopediatría_YosefDani_20170315_Ordenb.png
│       └── Cardiopediatría_YosefDani_20170315_Orden.png
├── Downloads
│   ├── Airy
│   ├── Bluetooth
│   └── Mac OS
├── Fotos Vuelo BOG-BAQ Yosef Dani
│   ├── 20160806_103440.jpg
│   ├── 20160806_103514.jpg
│   ├── 20160806_103516.jpg
│   ├── 20160806_103525.jpg
│   ├── 20160806_104555.jpg
│   ├── 20160806_104607.jpg
│   ├── 20160806_104609.jpg
│   ├── 20160806_104612.jpg
│   ├── 20160806_105022.mp4
│   ├── 20160806_105258.jpg
│   ├── 20160806_105305.jpg
│   ├── 20160806_105308.jpg
│   ├── 20160806_105313.jpg
│   ├── 20160806_105419.jpg
│   ├── 20160806_105422.jpg
│   ├── 20160806_105431.jpg
│   ├── 20160806_105438.jpg
│   ├── 20160806_105551.jpg
│   ├── 20160806_105554.jpg
│   ├── 20160806_113712.jpg
│   ├── 20160806_115037.mp4
│   ├── 20160806_115410.mp4
│   ├── 20160806_115743.mp4
│   ├── 20160806_120151.jpg
│   ├── 20160806_120153.jpg
│   ├── 20160806_120220.jpg
│   ├── 20160806_120222.jpg
│   ├── 20160806_120224.jpg
│   ├── 20160806_121526.mp4
│   ├── 20160806_122031.mp4
│   ├── 20160806_123037.mp4
│   ├── 20160806_130149.mp4
│   ├── 20160806_131413.mp4
│   ├── 20160806_133351.mp4
│   ├── 20160806_195105.jpg
│   ├── 20160806_195108.jpg
│   ├── 20160806_202530.jpg
│   ├── 20160806_211838.jpg
│   ├── 20160806_211842.jpg
│   ├── 20160807_104107.jpg
│   ├── 20160807_124445.mp4
│   ├── 20160807_124457.mp4
│   ├── 20160807_145344.jpg
│   ├── 20160807_145347.jpg
│   ├── 20160807_165909.jpg
│   ├── 20160807_182321.jpg
│   ├── 20160807_182324.jpg
│   ├── 20160807_182415.jpg
│   ├── 20160807_182433.jpg
│   ├── 20160807_182500.jpg
│   ├── 20160807_182511.jpg
│   ├── 20160807_182548.jpg
│   ├── 20160807_182653.jpg
│   ├── 20160807_182701.jpg
│   ├── 20160807_182934.jpg
│   ├── 20160807_182938.jpg
│   ├── 20160807_205001.jpg
│   ├── 20160807_210353.jpg
│   ├── 20160807_210404.jpg
│   ├── Como Ser Un Hijo De Dios
│   └── Icon\015
├── joseluisbz
│   ├── Desktop
│   ├── Documents
│   │   └── (102) Facebook.html
│   ├── Downloads
│   ├── Google Drive

│   │   ├── Factura MacBook Air.png
│   │   ├── GPON.gdoc
│   │   ├── Icon\015
│   │   ├── Itelkom.gdoc
│   │   └── LinksForMacOS.txt
│   ├── iRedMail
│   │   ├── Configure Outlook to use iRedMail accounts — iRedMail Support — iRedMail.html
│   │   ├── iredmail not sending or receiving _ DigitalOcean.html
│   │   └── IRedmail Troubleshooting logs — iRedMail Support — iRedMail.html
│   └── Pictures
│       ├── Photo Booth Library
│       │   ├── Contents
│       │   │   └── PkgInfo
│       │   ├── Originals
│       │   └── Pictures
│       ├── Photo on 3-12-17 at 14.59 #2.jpg
│       ├── Photo on 3-12-17 at 14.59.jpg
│       └── Photo on 3-12-17 at 15.07 #2.jpg
├── Kingston8GB
│   ├── AUTODESK.AUTOCAD.V2015.ES.WIN32.WIN64-ISO
│   │   ├── AUTODESK.AUTOCAD.V2015.ES.WIN32-ISO
│   │   │   ├── AutoCAD_2015_Spanish_Win_32bit_dlm.sfx.exe
│   │   │   ├── Crack
│   │   │   │   └── install.txt
│   │   │   ├── Instrucciones.txt
│   │   │   ├── nfo.nfo
│   │   │   └── www.intercambiosvirtuales.org.url
│   │   ├── AUTODESK.AUTOCAD.V2015.ES.WIN64-ISO
│   │   │   ├── AutoCAD_2015_Spanish_Win_64bit_dlm.sfx.exe
│   │   │   ├── Crack
│   │   │   │   └── install.txt
│   │   │   ├── Instrucciones.txt
│   │   │   ├── nfo.nfo
│   │   │   └── www.intercambiosvirtuales.org.url
│   │   ├── Información.txt
│   │   └── www.intercambiosvirtuales.org.url

│   ├── fotos Taekwondo
│   │   ├── IMG_3092.JPG
│   │   ├── IMG_3093.JPG
│   │   ├── IMG_3094.JPG
│   │   ├── IMG_3095.JPG
│   │   ├── IMG_3097.JPG
│   │   ├── IMG_3098.JPG
│   │   ├── IMG_3099.JPG
│   │   ├── IMG_3100.JPG
│   │   ├── IMG_3101.JPG
│   │   ├── IMG_3102.JPG
│   │   ├── IMG_3103.JPG
│   │   ├── IMG_3104.JPG
│   │   ├── IMG_3105.JPG
│   │   ├── IMG_3106.JPG
│   │   ├── IMG_3107.JPG
│   │   ├── IMG_3108.JPG
│   │   └── IMG_3109.JPG
│   ├── NetBeansProjects
│   │   ├── corion.htm
│   │   └── FacebookVideoCallSetup_v1.2.203.0.exe
│   ├── PORTAFOLIO 2015 - FINAL CLIENTE(ALD).pptx
│   ├── PORTAFOLIO 2015 - MODF 2.pptx
│   ├── PORTAFOLIO 2015 - MODF 3.pptx
│   ├── Presentacion como funciona M@icrotel.pptx
│   ├── SG
│   └── subtitleworkshop251.zip
├── Peliculas
│   └── Alien-Covenant.2017.KOR.HDRip.1080p.mkv
├── Snippet.txt
├── SoftwareDownloads
│   ├── CompilingPrograms
│   │   ├── apr-1.6.2.tar.gz
│   │   ├── apr-util-1.6.0.tar.gz
│   │   ├── bison-2.4.1-setup.exe
│   │   ├── cmake-3.7.2-win64-x64.zip
│   │   └── cmake-3.9.0.tar.gz
│   ├── drupal-8.3.6.tar.gz
│   ├── drupal-8.3.7
│   ├── drupal-8.3.7.tar.gz
│   ├── LNX
│   │   ├── 12.5.6.LIN.rar
│   │   ├── CentOS-7-x86_64-DVD-1611.iso
│   │   ├── dukto-6.0-14.1.x86_64.rpm
│   │   └── dukto-debuginfo-6.0-14.1.x86_64.rpm
│   ├── MAC
│   │   ├── DuktoR6-OSX.dmg
│   │   ├── MEGAsyncSetup.dmg
│   │   ├── MonoFramework-MDK-5.0.1.1.macos10.xamarin.universal.pkg
│   │   ├── vlc-2.2.6.dmg
│   │   └── VMware Tools
│   │       └── Install VMware Tools.app
│   │           └── Contents
│   │               ├── _CodeSignature
│   │               │   └── CodeResources
│   │               ├── Info.plist
│   │               └── MacOS
│   ├── netbeans-8.2-201609300101.zip
│   ├── SDKRef.pdf
│   ├── VirtualBox-5.1.26
│   ├── VirtualBox-5.1.26.tar.bz2
│   ├── VirtualBoxSDK-5.1.26-117224.zip
│   ├── VS 2017 Community
│   │   └── vs_community__998797103.1501553233.exe
│   └── WIN
│       └── 7601.17514.101119-1850_x64fre_server_eval_en-us-GRMSXEVAL_EN_DVD.iso
└── VirtualMachines
    ├── Centos 7 1511 64bits
    │   └── Centos 7 1511 64bits.vbox
    ├── MacOS 10.12 Sierra 64bits
    │   ├── Logs
    │   ├── MacOS 10.12 Sierra 64bits_20170511(OtherLoginUserM).vdi
    │   ├── MacOS 10.12 Sierra 64bits_20170629(with_dukto).vdi
    │   ├── MacOS 10.12 Sierra 64bits_20170809(Compiling).vdi
    │   ├── MacOS 10.12 Sierra 64bits.vbox
    │   └── MacOS 10.12 Sierra 64bits.vbox-prev
    ├── new.vbox
    │   ├── TestLnx.vbox
    │   ├── TestLnx.vbox-prev
    │   ├── TestMacElCapitan.vbox
    │   ├── TestMacElCapitan.vbox-prev
    │   ├── TestMac.vbox
    │   ├── TestMac.vbox-prev
    │   ├── TestWin.vbox
    │   └── TestWin.vbox-prev
    ├── Test_macOS
    ├── VirtualBox.xml
    ├── VirtualBox.xml-prev
    ├── VMwareFusion
    │   ├── CentOS
    │   ├── com.vmware.fusion.bin.plist
    │   └── Windows
    ├── Windows 10 Enterprise 64bits
    ├── Windows 10 Enterprise 64bits BigSizeHD
    └── Windows 7 Ultimate 32bits

150 directories, 365 files
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$
```

Comment: Does the drive even spinup?  Is it recognized? Have you tried the long arduous process of making a forensic image with `ddrescue` ?

Comment: When dealing with failing hardware time is of the essence. If the drive spins up and continues spinning you still have a shot. You will need a drive of equal or greater size to contain the image.

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't conceive of a way to recover data from a failing device without having a properly working device to put it on. Perhaps you can conceive of a way to obtaining a properly working device. Do you have the capability to place the drive in another enclosure to rule out electronics failure of the current enclosure as a root cause?

Comment: To recover files? Necessary, No. depending on the source and target filesystems you may lose permissions data (security). If you need further detail, you might find this related post useful. https://askubuntu.com/questions/96923/how-do-i-change-permissions-on-a-fat32-formatted-drive As you may have noticed data recovery is a time consuming process. Sometimes it's best to put the job in the hands of an experienced professional, especially if the data is valuable.

Comment: HFS+ is an interesting file system. If you are interested in some background there's some decent information on HFS on page 37 [here](http://www.nobius.org/~dbg/practical-file-system-design.pdf) and there's some good detail on HFS+ In the Ubuntu documentation https://help.ubuntu.com/community/hfsplus

Comment: I don't know what stage of the process you are referring to. the ddrescue manual is here: https://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/manual/ddrescue_manual.html The testdisk manual is here: https://www.cgsecurity.org/testdisk.pdf

Comment: Your `ddrescue` output is less than encouraging. I'm hoping that was an early paste and not the end result.